# How could I integrate a common javascript file into a LitElement file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lit-element

I'm trying to call a javaScript function that's in `functions/test.mjs` file to `src/components/capacitacion-contact-form.js` file, but when I try it, doesn't work and I have the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '../../../node_modules/emailjs/rollup/email.cjs' does not provide an export named 'SMTPClient'`

```
//capacitacion-contact-form.js
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';
import main from '../../../functions/test.mjs';

class CapacitacionContactForm extends LitElement {

static get properties() { return { formType: { type: String } } }

render() {
    return html`
        <form id="form">
            <div class="enviar">
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="boton-enviar"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    `;
}

_formSubmit(e, form) {

    var parsedForm = {}
    parsedForm.formType = this.formType

    //here should be the main function from `test.js`
    //main(`${parsedForm.email}`,"",`${parsedForm.formType}`,`<h1>a</h1>`);
   }
}

//###########################################
//test.mjs
import { SMTPClient } from 'emailjs';

async function main(a, b, c, d) {
  const client = new SMTPClient({ host: '', user: '', password: '', port: 26, ssl: false, tls: false 
});

try {
    const message = await client.sendAsync({ from: a, to: b, subject: c, attachment: [{ data: `${d}`, alternative: true }]});
}catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
}
```

Is there a way to do this? or another way to implement that but within `capacitacion-contact-form.js` without `test.js`?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the npm emailjs is not exporting SMTPClient which is weird as I can see in the docs that it is exporting it, I'm guessing is a version issue, can you check what version are you using?

As far as I can see SMTPClient got introduced at v3.0.0, here you can see it https://github.com/eleith/emailjs/commit/72f45ac15f9e21d87e53ce8e04d2b0c4bb14bc3c#diff-80b617a8b1de7375460f98ba809823e02d29501f8e7b3b17cc714cc78f282e10

Comment: @angel-xmu I'm using this version `emailjs: ^3.4.0`